# Imagens dentro de DIV's - Como?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Quero aplicar 2 logos de empresas, uma no lado esquerdo e outra no lado direito dentro desta DIV. Como?!
Só consigo aplicar uma, quando vou aplicar outra, a primeira some.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
@media (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1980px) and (min-height: 1024px) and (min-height: 1080px) {
*{
    font-family: Oswald;
}

.box {
    margin-left: -110px;
    width: 170%;
}

.box-chart {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body{
  background-color: #363636;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.painel-principal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 910px;
  border: 1px solid #FDCA2E;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: Oswald;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
.linhaS {
  width: 19.1111%;
  height: 880px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}

.cabecalho-topo p {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FDCA2E;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.cabecalho-inferior p {
  width: 100%;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cabecalho-inferior-whs p {
  width: 100%;
  /*margin-bottom: 5px;*/
  background: #FDCA2E;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}

.linha{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.linha:before,
.linha:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.linha:after {
    clear: both;
}

.linha {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.linha:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.inicio .row{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width: 272px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.inicio .oee{
  width: 282px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #FDCA2E;
  background-color: #FDCA2E;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.inicio .porcentagem{
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 284px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.controle .column{
  width: 29.4333%;
  background: #FDCA2E;
  border: 1px solid #FDCA2E;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.controle-2 .perc{
  width: 29.4333%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.controle-3 .rate{
  width: 55%;
  background: #FDCA2E;
  border: 1px solid #FDCA2E;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.controle-3 .head{
  width: 36.5333%;
  background: #FDCA2E;
  border: 1px solid #FDCA2E;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.controle-4{
  width: 55%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.controle-5{
  width: 36.5333%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.prod .prods{
  width: 95%;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 5px;
  min-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grafico .plaxpro{
  width: 95%;
  background: #FDCA2E;
  border: 1px solid #FDCA2E;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  min-height: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.perc-plaxpro{
  width: 95%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.perc-plaxpro .pla{
  color: #FF0000;
}
.perc-plaxpro .pro{
  color: #FDCA2E;
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt" class="no-js">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>DASHBOARD OEE - v1</title>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <link rel="icon" href="css/imagens/dhl_icon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <script src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   var randomnb = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*300)};
 </script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="cabecalho-topo">
  <p>OEE DASHBOARD</p>
</div>

<div class="painel-principal">

  <div class="linhaS"><!-- /PAINEL DA LINHA A -->

     <div class="inicio">
        <div class="row">LINHA A</div>
        <div class="oee">OEE</div>
      <div class="porcentagem">0%</div>
     </div>

      <div class="controle">
        <div class="column">DESEMP.</div>
        <div class="column">DISPONIB.</div>
        <div class="column">QUALID.</div>
       </div>

      <div class="controle-2">
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-3">
       <div class="rate">RATE</div>
       <div class="head">HEAD</div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-4">
       <div class="meta">Meta(cx/h): </div>
       <div class="real">Real(cx/h): </div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-5">
       <div>0</div>
       <div>0</div>
      </div>

      <div class="prod">
       <div class="prods">(Nome do produto)</div>
      </div>

      <div class="grafico">
       <div class="plaxpro">Planejado x Produzido</div>
      </div>

      <div class="perc-plaxpro">
       <div class="pla">Planejado: &emsp; null</div>
       <div class="pro">Produzido: &emsp; null</div>
      </div>

      <div class="box">

            <div class="box-chart">

                <canvas id="GraficoDonut1" style="width:100%;"></canvas>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                    var options = {
                        responsive:true
                    };

                    var data = [
                        {
                            value: randomnb(),
                            color:"#F7464A",
                            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                            label: "Planejado"
                        },
                        {
                            value: randomnb(),
                            color: "#FDCA2E",
                            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                            label: "Produzido"
                        }
                    ]



                        var ctx = document.getElementById("GraficoDonut1").getContext("2d");
                        var PizzaChart1 = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, options);

                </script>

            </div>

        </div>
  </div><!-- / FIM DO PAINEL DA LINHA A -->

 <div class="linhaS"><!-- /PAINEL DA LINHA B -->

     <div class="inicio">
      <div class="row">LINHA B</div>
      <div class="oee">OEE</div>
      <div class="porcentagem">0%</div>
     </div>

      <div class="controle">
        <div class="column">DESEMP.</div>
        <div class="column">DISPONIB.</div>
        <div class="column">QUALID.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-2">
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-3">
       <div class="rate">RATE</div>
       <div class="head">HEAD</div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-4">
       <div class="meta">Meta(cx/h): </div>
       <div class="real">Real(cx/h): </div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-5">
       <div>0</div>
       <div>0</div>
      </div>

      <div class="prod">
       <div class="prods">(Nome do produto)</div>
      </div>

      <div class="grafico">
       <div class="plaxpro">Planejado x Produzido</div>
      </div>

      <div class="perc-plaxpro">
       <div class="pla">Planejado: &emsp; null</div>
       <div class="pro">Produzido: &emsp; null</div>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
            <div class="box-chart">
                <canvas id="GraficoDonut2" style="width:100%;"></canvas>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    var options = {
                        responsive:true
                    };

                    var data = [
                        {
                            value: randomnb(),
                            color:"#F7464A",
                            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                            label: "Planejado"
                        },
                        {
                            value: randomnb(),
                            color: "#FDCA2E",
                            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                            label: "Produzido"
                        }
                    ]



                        var ctx = document.getElementById("GraficoDonut2").getContext("2d");
                        var PizzaChart2 = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, options);

                </script>
            </div>

        </div>
 </div><!-- / FIM DO PAINEL DA LINHA B -->

 <div class="linhaS"><!-- /PAINEL DA LINHA C -->

     <div class="inicio">
        <div class="row">LINHA C</div>
        <div class="oee">OEE</div>
      <div class="porcentagem">0%</div>
     </div>

      <div class="controle">
        <div class="column">DESEMP.</div>
        <div class="column">DISPONIB.</div>
        <div class="column">QUALID.</div>
       </div>

      <div class="controle-2">
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-3">
       <div class="rate">RATE</div>
       <div class="head">HEAD</div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-4">
       <div class="meta">Meta(cx/h): </div>
       <div class="real">Real(cx/h): </div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-5">
       <div>0</div>
       <div>0</div>
      </div>

      <div class="prod">
       <div class="prods">(Nome do produto)</div>
      </div>

      <div class="grafico">
       <div class="plaxpro">Planejado x Produzido</div>
      </div>

      <div class="perc-plaxpro">
       <div class="pla">Planejado: &emsp; null</div>
       <div class="pro">Produzido: &emsp; null</div>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
            <div class="box-chart">
                <canvas id="GraficoDonut3" style="width:100%;"></canvas>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    var options = {
                        responsive:true
                    };

                    var data = [
                        {
                            value: randomnb(),
                            color:"#F7464A",
                            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                            label: "Planejado"
                        },
                        {
                            value: randomnb(),
                            color: "#FDCA2E",
                            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                            label: "Produzido"
                        }
                    ]



                        var ctx = document.getElementById("GraficoDonut3").getContext("2d");
                        var PizzaChart3 = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, options);

                </script>
            </div>

        </div>
  </div><!-- / FIM DO PAINEL DA LINHA C -->

 <div class="linhaS"><!-- /PAINEL DA  LINHA D -->

     <div class="inicio">
        <div class="row">LINHA D</div>
        <div class="oee">OEE</div>
      <div class="porcentagem">0%</div>
     </div>

      <div class="controle">
        <div class="column">DESEMP.</div>
        <div class="column">DISPONIB.</div>
        <div class="column">QUALID.</div>
       </div>

      <div class="controle-2">
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-3">
       <div class="rate">RATE</div>
       <div class="head">HEAD</div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-4">
       <div class="meta">Meta(cx/h): </div>
       <div class="real">Real(cx/h): </div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-5">
       <div>0</div>
       <div>0</div>
      </div>

      <div class="prod">
       <div class="prods">(Nome do produto)</div>
      </div>

      <div class="grafico">
       <div class="plaxpro">Planejado x Produzido</div>
      </div>

      <div class="perc-plaxpro">
       <div class="pla">Planejado: &emsp; null</div>
       <div class="pro">Produzido: &emsp; null</div>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
            <div class="box-chart">
                <canvas id="GraficoDonut4" style="width:100%;"></canvas>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    var options = {
                        responsive:true
                    };

                    var data = [
                        {
                            value: randomnb(),
                            color:"#F7464A",
                            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                            label: "Planejado"
                        },
                        {
                            value: randomnb(),
                            color: "#FDCA2E",
                            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                            label: "Produzido"
                        }
                    ]



                        var ctx = document.getElementById("GraficoDonut4").getContext("2d");
                        var PizzaChart4 = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, options);

                </script>
            </div>

        </div>
  </div><!-- / FIM DO PAINEL DA LINHA D -->

 <div class="linhaS"><!-- /PAINEL DA LINHA E -->

     <div class="inicio">
        <div class="row">LINHA E</div>
        <div class="oee">OEE</div>
      <div class="porcentagem">0%</div>
     </div>

      <div class="controle">
        <div class="column">DESEMP.</div>
        <div class="column">DISPONIB.</div>
        <div class="column">QUALID.</div>
       </div>

      <div class="controle-2">
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
       <div class="perc">0%</div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-3">
       <div class="rate">RATE</div>
       <div class="head">HEAD</div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-4">
       <div class="meta">Meta(cx/h): </div>
       <div class="real">Real(cx/h): </div>
      </div>

      <div class="controle-5">
       <div>0</div>
       <div>0</div>
      </div>

      <div class="prod">
       <div class="prods">(Nome do produto)</div>
      </div>

      <div class="grafico">
       <div class="plaxpro">Planejado x Produzido</div>
      </div>

      <div class="perc-plaxpro">
       <div class="pla">Planejado: &emsp; null</div>
       <div class="pro">Produzido: &emsp; null</div>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
            <div class="box-chart">
                <canvas id="GraficoDonut5" style="width:100%;"></canvas>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    var options = {
                        responsive:true
                    };

                    var data = [
                        {
                            value: randomnb(),
                            color:"#F7464A",
                            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                            label: "Planejado"
                        },
                        {
                            value: randomnb(),
                            color: "#FDCA2E",
                            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                            label: "Produzido"
                        }
                    ]



                        var ctx = document.getElementById("GraficoDonut5").getContext("2d");
                        var PizzaChart5 = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, options);

                </script>
            </div>

        </div>
  </div><!-- / FIM DO PAINEL DA LINHA E -->

</div><!-- /FIM DO PAINEL PRINCIPAL -->

<div class="cabecalho-inferior">
 <p><marquee>Planejado(Turno): &emsp; null  &emsp; Realizado(turno): &emsp; null  &emsp; %Total: &emsp; null</marquee></p>
</div>

<div class="cabecalho-inferior-whs">
 <p>WHS DASHBOARD</p>
</div>

<!-- <div class="desenvolvido">
 <p> &copy; Alexandre Amado </p>
</div> -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mostre o seu código, a pergunta está longe de ser respondida com essa escassez de informações.

Comment: Pronto. Perdão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.hello{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.left{
  float: left;
}

.left img{
  width: 100px;
}

.right{
  float: right
}

.right img{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">
    <div class="left"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Mcdonalds-90s-logo.svg/1280px-Mcdonalds-90s-logo.svg.png"></div>
    <div class="right"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/694921357864386563/p0nF8Bj8.jpg"></div>
  </div>
```

É isso que você quer?

Comment: Quase! Porém, preciso que fique dentro da div as 2 imagens, uma na esquerda e outra na direita. Peguei seu código e editei um pouco, consegui colocar uma dentro, mas a outra não entra kkk

Comment: Estou editando aqui e quase conseguindo, você já me deu uma luz! Obrigado, acho que consigo prosseguir daqui.

Comment: @AlexandreAmado Precisando de ajudar me avisa :D

Comment: Voltei aqui pra dizer que consegui! Muito obrigado Rafael :D

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g04og3

Comment: @AlexandreAmado De nada, se puder deixa +1 ai :D

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isso pode te ajudar, voce pode colocar o logo em um canto ou do lado do outro só alterando o tamanho das col.

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <img src="" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img src="" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img src="" alt="">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anderson, não existe bootstrap nessa pergunta.

Comment: perdao descuido meu, só coloquei o trecho do codigo para o mesmo ter uma noção de como fazer pegando um exemplo do framework.